# replaceChild() to move images functioning only once in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, replace, children

I have 3 images side by side, and I have to put 2 buttons under them. Clicking on go forward, the images should move forward and change places, and go backward, vice versa. 
I've tried to get this done with arrays, but it is not responding. It moves only once, and does the same action on the one click whether forward or backward. I've pasted my code in the codepen, please have a look. Pasting code here gives me trouble.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JqZPVW

```
function goleft(){
    imgscroll[0] = document.createElement("imgscl");
    imgscroll[1] = document.createElement("imgscl");
    imgscroll[2] = document.createElement("imgscl");

    for(var index=0 ; index < 3; index++)
    {
        legendChildNodes[index] = document.getElementById("legends").childNodes[index];
        imgscroll[index].src = imgArray[index];
    }
    if(imgArray[0] == document.getElementById("legends").childNodes[0].src)
    {
        document.getElementById("legends").replaceChild(imgscroll[1], legendChildNodes[0]);
        document.getElementById("legends").replaceChild(imgscroll[2], legendChildNodes[1]);
        document.getElementById("legends").replaceChild(imgscroll[0], legendChildNodes[2]);
    }
    else if (imgArray[0] == document.getElementById("legends").childNodes[1].src)
    {
        document.getElementById("legends").replaceChild(imgscroll[2], legendChildNodes[0]);
        document.getElementById("legends").replaceChild(imgscroll[0], legendChildNodes[1]);
        document.getElementById("legends").replaceChild(imgscroll[1], legendChildNodes[2]);
    }
    else if (imgArray[0] == document.getElementById("legends").childNodes[2].src)
    {
        document.getElementById("legends").replaceChild(imgscroll[0], legendChildNodes[0]);
        document.getElementById("legends").replaceChild(imgscroll[1], legendChildNodes[1]);
        document.getElementById("legends").replaceChild(imgscroll[2], legendChildNodes[2]);
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me with this.

Comment: do you want the leftmost image to disappear when the Left button is pressed or do you want it to cycle and appear on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer above to append image nodes dynamically..., though will render the whole area each time you go left or right. (But with only one time loading for images);

Refer code here: https://codepen.io/JohnnyWang0530/pen/OYEJaJ

```html
<div id="legends"></div>
<button onclick="goTo('left')">GO LEFT</button>
<button onclick="goTo('right')">GO RIGHT</button>
```

```css
#legends img {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```js
// Create image Src
let imgSrc = [
  "https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/9646/HCBvlG.jpg",
  "https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/3295/Fb6gMO.jpg",
  "https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/6089/01GQK7.jpg"
];
// Create image Nodes for use later
let imgNodes = [];

// Init images & dynamically append them into "legend"
function createImages() {
  let legend = document.getElementById('legends');

  // create image nodes at first time executing
  if (imgNodes.length === 0) {
    for (let i=0;i<imgSrc.length;i++) {
      imgNodes[i] = document.createElement('IMG');
      imgNodes[i].src = imgSrc[i];
    }
  }

  // clear all each time you press left or right
  legend.innerHTML = '';

  // append image nodes
  for (let i=0;i<imgNodes.length;i++) {
    legend.appendChild(imgNodes[i]);
  }
}

// function for goLeft & goRight
function goTo(direct) {
  let output = [];
  for (let i=0;i<imgNodes.length;i++) {
    if (direct === 'left') {
      output[i] = imgNodes[i + 1];
      output[imgNodes.length - 1] = imgNodes[0];
    } else if (direct === 'right') {
      output[i] = imgNodes[i - 1];
      output[0] = imgNodes[imgNodes.length - 1];
    }
  }
  imgNodes = output;
  createImages();
}

// Initiate the function
createImages();
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. It also elaborates abelito's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some working code. I basically just remove the element and append it to the end, or insert it before the first element dynamically.

```
  function goleft() {
         let imageChildNodes = document.getElementById("legends").childNodes;
         let imageList = Array.from(imageChildNodes).filter(function(node) { return node.tagName === 'IMG'; });

         let legendsContainer = document.getElementById("legends");
         legendsContainer.removeChild(imageList[0]);
         legendsContainer.appendChild(imageList[0]);
    }

  function goright() {
         let imageChildNodes = document.getElementById("legends").childNodes;
         let imageList = Array.from(imageChildNodes).filter(function(node) { return node.tagName === 'IMG'; });

         let legendsContainer = document.getElementById("legends");
         legendsContainer.removeChild(imageList[imageList.length - 1]);
         legendsContainer.insertBefore(imageList[imageList.length - 1], imageList[0]); 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm amazed at how simple this code actually was.